# Show splash screen until PhoneGap loads home page

Tags: cordova, splash-screen

I created a phonegap application. It takes 4 seconds to load the main home page (ie. index.html).

Is there any way that I can show some Image/Splash Screen until phonegap loads the index.html ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the splash screen for something more than you expect, maybe 10 seconds.

Then use the following code to close it as soon as the page is ready:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple. If you put your splash.png image file into res/drawable-ldpi, res/drawable-mdpi, res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-xhdpi folders.Then in your main java class that extends DroidGap add this line:

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
```

Then modify the loadUrl method to pause for 5 seconds :

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 5000);
```

Happy coding.